# Convert a pojo variable to another bean which takes it as list of name and value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mapping, dozer, mapstruct

I have a bean with set of variables. I want to convert them to another bean say Parameters which has just name and value. I need to make the list of parameters of those all variables in name-value pair.

I am thinking of Dozer or mapstruct but this seems to be not really helpful.

Today, using objectmapper to convert it to maps,iterating over maps and creating the list of parameter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to copy variables from one bean to another?

Comment: If you provide a small example of how your beans look like I could help out more for MapStruct

Comment: yes Abhijit. i need to convert

Comment: I would suggest that you update your question with the example. Additionally, what you are trying to do is not really possible in Java. From what I understand the `name` in `Parameter` is actually the name of the field in the `TestClass`. For that to work you'll need to use reflection and that will only work correctly with Java 8 and the `-parameters` option.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class TestClass{
    private String str1;
    private String str2;
    private String str3;
    }

    Class Paramters{
    private String name;
    private String value;
    }

    **Bean1:**
    '[
        {
            "str1": "string",
            "str2": "string",
            "str3": "string"
        },
        {
            "str1": "string1",
            "str2": "string1",
            "str3": "string1"
        }
    ]'

    To Convert **Bean2**

   '[{
        "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "str1",
                "value": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "str2",
                "value": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "str3",
                "value": "string"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "str1",
                "value": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "str2",
                "value": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "str3",
                "value": "string"
            }
        ]}]'
```

Comment: @Filip hope the above example helps you to derive the answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mapstruct and the like generally convert from one bean to another, your are essentially trying to convert to a map and wrap that to a bean. 
Something like [BeanMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanMap.html) would be more appropriate.

Untested sample code:

```
class Bean2 {
    private final Map<String, Object> properties;

    public Bean2(Map properties) { this.properties = properties }


    public static class Entry { String name, String value /* getters and setters */}

    @JsonProperty
    public List<Map<String, Object>> getProperties() {
        // build a map of maps here, each map would have 
    } 
}
```

Then just:

```
new Bean2(new BeanMap(bean2))
```